# pyautogui typewrite() only outputs uppercase

Tags: python, pyautogui

I was making a script to type some text in the currently active text field. with research i found about typewrite(). But now my issue is it seems to only type in caps.

```
typewite("hello how are you")
#output
# HELLO HOW ARE YOU

#text.lower() doesnt work either
```

I am missing something or is it the way this is supposed to work?
Please help solve this or suggest alternatives..

Btw i am running python3 on Arch Linux(many post related to pyautogui had this info so i guess its needed)

Edit:
its seem the first typewriter() or any other function from pyautogui will always be in CAPS. the subsequent will be in lower cases

```
typewite("hello how are you")
typewite("hello how are you")

#output
# HELLO HOW ARE YOUhello how are you
```

you get the point....

Comment: Can you post your full code and its output?

Answer (score 0):

`pyautogui` uses your keyboard settings. If your Caps Lock is on, it will write uppercase. I can't say without seeing whether Caps Lock is on or not, but the problem is probably this.
By the way, not related but also language settings matter for typing without error.

edit:

This code works well when caps lock is off:

```
import pyautogui as pgui

pgui.press('win')
pgui.typewrite('notepad', 0.2)
pgui.PAUSE = 4
pgui.press('enter')
pgui.typewrite("hello how are you")
pgui.getWindowsWithTitle('Untitled')[0].close()
pgui.press('enter')
pgui.typewrite('foo' + '.txt')
pgui.press('enter')
```

Comment: I havn't turned caps lock on. but what is noticed was that if your code has just 2 typewrites() and nothing else. the first typewrite will output in all-caps , while the second one will be in lowercase.... super weird....

Comment: So, my answer is not valid. Maybe you can raise an issue at pyautogui's github repository. They'll probably take care of it. @HTPranav07

Answer (score 0):

The pyautogui docs say that "The primary keyboard function is `write()`.", so perhaps you could try using that instead of `typewrite()`?

https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#the-write-function